# Automatically create variable with accurate content by input

Tags: python

How can I create variable with name from result of input?

**Example:**

```
username = input()
result of username is example for John
```

Now I need to create variable with name John a content will be empty string.

```
John = ""
```

Comment: you dont. Thats not how variable names work. However you could create a dictionary: `myDictionary = { username : ""}` - see [dictionarys](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) thats stores your empty string under a key `"John"`

Comment: So, if I need to create automatically so many variables of any names, it is not possible, is not it?

Comment: Maybe you should follow a python tutorial that explains lists and data. If you need the user to input 10 names, you could store them in a list like so: `mylistofnames = []` which creates an empty list and then you repeat the input() 10 times: `for _ in range(10):` + `mylistofnames.append(input())`  ( you need to indent the stuff that should be looped by 4 spaces. See [for-loop-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and [list's](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: @J.Doe If you insist, it certainly is possible. Just set the dict returned by the built-in functions `globals()`. For example, `globals()['John'] = ''` is equivalent to `John = ''`.

Comment: @blhsing Can you post the code please?

Comment: @J.Doe I already did. `globals()['John'] = ''`.. or as your question requests, `globals()[input()] = ''`.

Comment: @blhsing theres advice and advice. yours ... is bad.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did put a disclaimer of "if you insist".